# Java not showing runtime errors/exceptions on async threads

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

I have sql queries that run asynchronously using

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        readFromDB();
        parseJSON();
    });
```

And no errors/exceptions are showing up, I even tried throwing random exception (`throw new EmptyStackException();`) and it doesn't show up in the console, printf() is working normally.

Why are errors/exceptions not showing up?

Comment: what do you mean with "showing up"? Where do you expect them?

Comment: Console is not showing them, code execution stops but I get no errors back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of runAsync, you can use supplyAsync(()-> and handle exception something like:

```
 supplyAsync(()-> {
         readFromDB();
         parseJSON();
    })
    .exceptionally(e-> {
         // your logic here
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, runtime errors and exceptions are printing to console.

Answer (score 2):

This is by design. To catch/handle an exception, one needs a synchronization point. By calling [`CompletableFuture.runAsync(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync(java.lang.Runnable)) the execution is explicitly decoupled from the current thread and thus has no synchronization point.

What one can do instead is store the created `CompletableFuture` and get its status, e.g. by calling [`join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join()):

```
final CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(...);
...
try {
    future.join(); // This will re-throw the exception that occured in the future, if any
} catch (final RuntimeException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, first solution worked for me, but I'm saving this incase I'll need it.